# Revert deleted node (or replace "Delete" with "Hide") in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal

I need to set up a content system in Drupal where accidentally deleted nodes can be retrieved. Is it possible to do it with any existing module?

If not, is there a module that let's me hide nodes instead of deleting them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a module for this, Drupal can do it out of the box. Simply use the unpublish option instead of deleting.

Also you should configure your permissions so users/admins can't delete nodes.

Comment: Thanks, that was simple enough :)

Comment: Can I move a "Unpublish" button to the place where "Delete" is?

Comment: You could create an unpublish submit button. It would require some work with a custom module, using `hook_form_alter` to do it, but should be simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

I answered your question here : 
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/645/is-it-possible-to-restore-a-deleted-node/118186#118186
P.S : should have been posted as comment here but i can add comments

Comment: As it is another site of the network (so, not a technical duplicate), you can post the same answer here. Right now, it's considered a "link-only" answer, and could be removed...